# Flutter web Webview ignores stack and nothing is clickable above the webview itself

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview, flutter-web

I have been using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)  on my flutter app for months and it is working perfectly,, the webview widget is a base of stack widgets and has some other buttons above it :

```dart
            Stack(
          childrens:[
          WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
          ),
                Positioned(
                    top:100,
                    bottom:100
                    child:MaterialButton();
            ),
        Positioned(
            top:200,
            bottom:200
            child:MaterialButton();
    ),
        ]
    );
```

in this case, it works fine and both `Android` and `IOS`, but when I switched to the web by using [webview_flutter_web](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_web)  and added the default web view as follows in my `main.dart` :

```dart
  if (kIsWeb) {
    WebView.platform = WebWebViewPlatform();
  } else {
    WebView.platform = AndroidWebView();
  }
```

the `Webview` itself worked, but the buttons above it are not clickable .. when click on It is interacts like am clicking the webview itself

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I posted [a similar issue to the flutter github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123343). There appears to be an issue in the webview package. For now, you can wrap widgets with the [PointerInterceptor widget](https://pub.dev/packages/pointer_interceptor).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Can't upvote this thread. So I will try to provide some additional documentation.
I had a similar use case.. I am using a webGL rendered website (written in HTML and CSS) in a Flutter Web app using `webview_flutter_web`. And I was trying to use a `Stack` widget with a simple button on top of the WebView and had the same error. Came to the thread -> went to the [github thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123343#issuecomment-1487626493) -> and then used the mentioned package [pointer_interceptor](https://pub.dev/packages/pointer_interceptor):

```
class ExamplePage extends StatelessWidget{
  ExamplePage({super.key});

  final PlatformWebViewController _controller = PlatformWebViewController(
    const PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams(),
  )..loadRequest(
    LoadRequestParams(
      uri: Uri.parse('ANY-URL-HERE'),
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          PlatformWebViewWidget(
            PlatformWebViewWidgetCreationParams(controller: _controller),
          ).build(context),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: PointerInterceptor(
              child: const NotifyButton(),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!